# Using Delete By Query API and Bulk API together in Elastic

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5, elasticsearch-bulk-api, elasticsearch-api

I couldn't see any documentation/example about using delete by query api with bulk api in elastic search.

Simply, I want to delete all the documents having same `A` field and insert many documents just after that. If delete process fails, it shouldn't insert any documents.

e.g.

```
POST _bulk
{ "index" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "_id" : "1" } }
{ "field1" : "value1" }
??? { "delete_by_query???" : { "_index" : "test", "_type" : "type1", "query"... } }
```

Is there any way to use them together?
Thanks.

Comment: This is not supported by the bulk endpoint, it's easier to handle that in your application logic. (note that in your sample you do exactly the opposite as you described)

Comment: The main reason being that delete-by-query can be a very long process, in contrary to index/update/delete operations

Comment: Ok then, I'm going to handle that in api. Thanks